# Measuring voltage across a rheostat

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement, voltmeter, rheostat

I want to measure the voltage across a rheostat. For this purpose I connected a voltmeter in parallel to it, but even on turning on the circuit there was no deflection in the voltmeter whatsoever. What shall I do?

The series resistor has a resistance value of 100 Ω.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your diode is connected in the correct polarity?

Comment: Yes, there was current through the diode(in mA) as per the multimeter i used.

Comment: What's the voltage of the battery?  Resistances of the the adjustable and fixed resistors?  Part number of the diode?

Comment: @vir I used a 9V battery connected to a fixed carbon resistor of 100 ohms, and an adjustable resistor having a 50 ohms range, I'm not sure about the part number of the diode though. Well, i feel there's some issue with the voltmeter's connection with the adjustable resistor

Comment: 9V across 100 ohms will dissipate 810mW.  Unlikely but possible that during initial connection, you had the rheostat all the way to 0 ohms and burned out the resistor.  Even with the rheostat at 50 ohms that's still 360mW.  Try measuring the resistance of the 100 ohm resistor.

Comment: If you measured the current incorrectly you may have blown a fuse in your meter and all subsequent voltage measurements could read zero (depending on where the fuse is in the multimeter circuit).

Comment: It would help us if you also posted a picture of your complete set-up. Perhaps the schematic does not accurately represent the actual components and connections.

Answer (score 3):

- If the rheostat was damaged, as in open, all the voltage from the battery would appear across the rheostat terminals.
  Vrheostat = Vbattery.
- Is your meter on the wrong scale for the voltage you are measuring, or on AC instead of DC?
- If the rheostat is not bad, be sure to measure the voltage across the diode, and the battery.
- If the diode is in backward, all the battery voltage will appear across the diode.
- Check the other resistor is good.
  Do the math, calculate your drops and expected voltages.
- I only once have come across a resistor in a circuit that was open, and it was not in a circuit that I would say was stressful to that resistor.
- Sometimes parts expire.
- Measure the battery so you know it is good, and can see if it is under load: in-circuit battery voltage has dropped vs out of circuit value.
- "Load" = current flow.
- E/I=R. If the voltage dropped, what components can account for that in-circuit resistance? Is that drop normal for this circuit?
- Check your meter wires with ohm function.
- Wiggle the whole circuit, it may be a bad connection.
- Is this on a breadboard? They don't last forever, either.
- Bad battery clip connection?
- Have you tried varing the position of the rheostats shaft?
- How many turns does the rheostat have?

Comment: That more than covers all possibilities, I think. I often wonder about the abilities of those who ask such questions, and their apparent paucity of troubleshooting experience and techniques.

Comment: Written with a lot of fantasy and imagination... I especially like the cases where "all the battery voltage will appear across the rheostat or diode"... and also the idea to "wiggle the whole circuit" and "varing the position of the rheostats shaft" (poor contact between wiper and resistor?)...

Comment: The rheostat should present itself in the circuit as a resistor in series and always present itself as 50Ω unless the resistive strip is broken. The shaft introduces a parallel resistance down to zero Ω. If the strip is broken, there will be a zone of the wiper arm working, then definitely something wrong > open circuit. If the meter jumps unevenly while adjust the wiper, the wiper contact is dirty, or the strip has flaws in the surface, or has a break.

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes:

- The resistance of the rheostat is zero (its wiper is in the extreme position)
- The rheostat is shorted (shunted) by an external circuit
- No supply voltage

And some experiments in the spirit of @Magic_Smoke's ones:

- Remove the rheostat. If the voltmeter shows the source voltage, then the rheostat had zero resistance.
- Shunt the resistor with another resistor. If the voltmeter shows voltage, then the resistor has been broken.
- Shunt the diode with another resistor (or just by a piece of wire). If the voltmeter shows voltage, then the diode has been broken.
- Replace the voltmeter with another one. Do the same with the rest of the elements (the most straightforward experiment).
- Reverse the battery. This will help if you have reversed the diode.
- Keep one probe of the voltmeter stationary and the other moving along its resistive layer if it is accessible. The voltage should change in proportion to the displacement.